# Fabric.js on Node causes memory usage to top 512mb on Heroku

Tags: heroku, fabricjs

I have an app on Heroku in which I generate a PDF from a series of canvases but it often tops the memory quota of 512mb, even when the canvases are empty. I think the problem lies in `canvas.loadFromJSON()` Here's the code I use. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
doc = new PDFDocument({size:[pageWidth, pageHeight]})

for (var i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
  canvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas()
  canvas.setWidth(canvasWidth)
  canvas.setHeight(canvasHeight)
  if ( publication && publication.pages.hasOwnProperty('p' + i) ) { // if not empty
    canvas.loadFromJSON(publication.pages['p' + i])
    delete publication.pages['p' + i]
    SVGtoPDF(doc, canvas.toSVG(), 0, 0)
    canvas.clear()
    canvas.dispose()
    if (i != 8) {
      doc.addPage()
    }
  }
  delete publication
  delete canvas
}

doc.pipe(res).on('finish', function() {
  console.log('single page pdf was successfully created by ' + process.pid)
})

doc.end()
```